# Qt - How to use rich text in a QComboBox?

Tags: qt, richtext, qcombobox

I am trying to use rich text in a QComboBox but it does not support it. Perhaps I should write a subclass? But I am unsure on what I would need to override as I have never done anything like this before. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think [custom delegate class](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/model-view-delegate.html) is the answer. The solution is to simply replace standard drawing routine with your own (using i.e. QLabel). There was a similar question here: [QListView/QListWidget with custom items and custom item widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948444/qlistview-qlistwidget-with-custom-items)