# Can QComboBox items text consist of 2 colors?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

For example for string "Elon Musk":

- "Elon" text color is red;
- "Musk" text color is green;

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: You can have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2039745/6165833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative approach to using delegates I would use a `QLabel` with rich text (HTML encoded) to color the combo box item text. I also need to implement an event filter to handle clicking (selecting) "custom" items. The following example demonstrates how to do it:

```
class Filter : public QObject
{
public:
  Filter(QComboBox *combo)
    :
      m_combo(combo)
  {}
protected:
  bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent * event) override
  {
    auto lbl = qobject_cast<QLabel *>(watched);
    if (lbl && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
      // Set the current index
      auto model = m_combo->model();
      for (int r = 0; r < model->rowCount(); ++r)
      {
        if (m_combo->view()->indexWidget(model->index(r, 0)) == lbl)
        {
          m_combo->setCurrentIndex(r);
          break;
        }
      }
      m_combo->hidePopup();
    }
    return false;
  }

private:
  QComboBox *m_combo;
};
```

And here is how to add "colored" items into combo box and handle them:

```
QComboBox box;
box.setEditable(true);
Filter filter(&box);

// Add two items: regular and colored.
box.addItem("A regular item");
box.addItem("Elon Musk");

// Handle the colored item. Color strings using HTML tags.
QLabel lbl("<font color=\"red\">Elon </font><font color=\"green\">Musk</font>", &box);
lbl.setAutoFillBackground(true);
lbl.installEventFilter(&filter);
box.view()->setIndexWidget(box.model()->index(1, 0), &lbl);

box.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. In fact you can do whatever you want in there using [QItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html). Inside the delegate you can do all the crazy stuff you want, which not only includes coloring, but also buttons and other controls.

Comment: Thank you for response. I'm not sure where exactly to change colors, but I will be searching in direction of sub-classing of QStyledItemDelegate and reimplementing of paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)  method. So changing "option" I hope to solve my problem

Comment: [`QStyledItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#details) is recommended by the doc instead of `QItemDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with Qt::ItemDataRole to provide customisations. For this particular case -

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QColor>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QComboBox box;
    box.addItem("Elon");
    box.addItem("Musk");

    box.setItemData(0, QColor(Qt::red), Qt::ForegroundRole);
    box.setItemData(1, QColor(Qt::green), Qt::ForegroundRole);

    box.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Screenshots for reference -

[image]
[image]

Comment: So detailed answer,  thanks a lot. But gave a confusing description of my question, sorry for that. 
I meant: "Elon Musk" is the one item (not two)

Comment: But the question was about coloring strings in a single item. I.e. "Elon Musk" is the text in a single item, where "Elon (red) Musk (green)".

Comment: @Igor you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476581/qt-how-to-use-rich-text-in-a-qcombobox