# How to customize the display of a QListView

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractlistmodel

I have implemented a list of users in my `Qt` program, using the **model/view** principle of `Qt`. My `QListView` displays a subclass of `QAbstractListModel` and so far this works just fine.

Now I would like to customize the display of my user list (display the name on several line, add IP information, and so on: not really relevant, I just want something really custom).

I couldn't find anything in the `Qt` documentation regarding this: what are my options ?

Note: The items in the list do not need to (*can't*) be modified, if this can help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new [item delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html) class to handle the painting. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948444/qlistview-qlistwidget-with-custom-items) is a good answer to a similar question.