# Custom items in Tree View Widget

Tags: qt4

I'm working on a instant messaging client and i am looking for a way to display the contacts like Pigdin or Yahoo Messenger does.
I was looking at a Tree Widget, but is there a way to customize the items?
I would like them to look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be better to use QTreeView instead of QTreeWidget. Then you can use the Qt's [model/view](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/model-view-programming.html) system and create a new [item delegate](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qitemdelegate.html) class to handle the painting.

And read also this question: [QListView/QListWidget with custom items and custom item widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948444/qlistview-qlistwidget-with-custom-items)

Answer (score 2):

I have a project that might be of some interest to you. It's qt4 based and includes a Jabber messenger client - and a contact list with icons.

> http://saje.googlecode.com