# Is it possible to use busy progressbar with normal functionality in QListView?

Tags: qt

I have created by myself model (**MyListModel**) that store list of my objects **MyObj**. **MyObj** stores some text information. Then I created class **ItemDelegate**, in order to manage view of every item and also to add **QProgressBar** to each item. The problem is that I need busy progressbar, but when I execute app, QProgressBar doesn't do any action.[image: busy progressbar don't work]

I'm guessing, it's because **QListView** only show static data. Is there any way to make it work properly?
My realisation of paint method for Delegate:

```
void StatusItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    StatusItem my_item = index.data().value<StatusItem>();
    wdg->name->setText(my_item.m_name);
    switch (my_item.m_state)
    {
        case 0: wdg->progress->setMaximum(0);  wdg->progress->setMinimum(0); break;
        case 1: wdg->progress->setRange(0, 0); wdg->progress->setValue(100); break;
        case 2: wdg->progress->setHidden(true); break;
    }
    QPalette pal;
    QLinearGradient gradient(0, 0, 0, 100);

    if ((option.state & QStyle::State_Selected) == QStyle::State_Selected)
    {
        pal.setBrush(QPalette::Window, QBrush(QColor(0, 255, 200)));
    }
    else
    {
        gradient.setColorAt(0.0, QColor(255,250,0));
        gradient.setColorAt(1.0, QColor(255,255,255));
        pal.setBrush(QPalette::Window, QBrush(QColor(Qt::transparent)));
        pal.setBrush(QPalette::Window, QBrush(gradient));
    }
  wdg->setPalette(pal);
  wdg->resize(option.rect.size());
  painter->save();
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
  painter->translate(option.rect.topLeft());
  wdg->render(painter);

  painter->restore();
}
```

Comment: Maybe [QListView with custom items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948444/qlistview-qlistwidget-with-custom-items) can help a bit.

Comment: Show the delegate code at least.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm using already custom items, but it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem exists because the view repaints items only when something is changed. While model data remains unchanged, according cells are not repainted.

In this situation you should cause additional repaints from the delegate. Unfortunately there is no convenient way to do it, but there are longer ways. You need to do the following action in the `paint` method:

```
view->update(index);
```

There are two issues:

1. You don't have `view` pointer in the `paint` method. You can either try to use `painter->device()` and assume that this is the view's viewport (but it's not guaranteed) or store `view` in the delegate's class member variable.
2. Calling `update` inside `paint` can cause infinite recursion (I'm not sure about this one). If that's the case, you can delay `update` using `QTimer::singleShot(0, ...)`. But you will need to create a slot for that somewhere an pass `view` and `index` somehow so that they will be accessible in the slot.

Comment: `view->update(index);` inside `paint` method don't work, calling this function from other place, to check if it'll help, is hard because `paint` method is `const`, and it's impossible to store `QModelIndex` (paint's argument) inside `QItemDelegate`, maybe it will work if create signal that will send `QModelIndex` and slot that will do `view->update(index);`. But for me simpliest solution is to use `QListWidget`, where busy progressbar works propely.